# Team foundation server, SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

We restored our TFS 2013 database backups on separate data tier with SQL Server 2012. Now I am trying to add these databases to TFS server (it's a sandpit tier), where I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 version. While running app tier wizard, I added SQL instance but it is throwing an error:

> TF400860: the current version of following service is not supported registry Version 5, min version 5

Both servers have same version of TFS (TFS 2013.5)

Can anyone advise how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that is actually descriptive of the question you're asking or problem you're having. You've simply repeated information already available from the tags. Your title should be descriptive enough to have meaning to a future user who sees it in a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum SQL version for 2013 is SQL 2012 with SP1 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements

Answer (score 0):

The minimum SQL server requirement for TFS 2013 is SQL server 2008 R2 (SP1).

The solution for this error is, **we need to change the SQL server instance availability group as primary by logging in to same server**
We have 4 data tiers, which are in sync, I tried it and I got it with SQL version 2008 R2. No need of SQL version 2012 or higher.

Thanks